# Выравнивание по горизонтали кнопки и текста

Tags: html, css, выравнивание

Доброго времени суток, как выровнить кнопку с текстом на одной строчке? Дело в том, что из-за большого текста, он не встает в одну строчку и переходит на следующую.

```html
<div style="padding: 0 20px;">
  <div style="display: inline-block;">
    [button title="СКАЧАТЬ" icon="icon-download" icon_position="left" link="documents/ustav.doc" target="_blank"]
  </div>
  <div style="display: inline-block;">
    <p style="font-size: 20px; color: #3b4146;">- Устав автомобильного транспорта</p>
  </div>
</div>

[divider height="30" style="default" line="default" themecolor="1"]
<div style="padding: 0 20px;">
  <div style="display: inline-block;">
    [button title="СКАЧАТЬ" icon="icon-download" icon_position="left" link="documents/fz257.doc" target="_blank"]
  </div>
  <div style="display: inline-block;">
    <p style="font-size: 20px; color: #3b4146;">- ФЗ РФ № 257 "Об автомобильных дорогах и о дорожной деятельности в Российской Федерации и о внесении изменений в отдельные законодательные акты Российской Федерации"</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3ezcymyr/

Comment: @soledar10  а почему inline недостаточно?

Comment: можно и с display: inline-block - необходимо задать ширину и убрать отступ + box-sizing: border-box - приблизительно так - https://jsfiddle.net/vamkr1fb/

Comment: здорово! а чего вы как ответ не оформили? Я конечно, не автор вопроса, но я бы принял ваш ответ :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант 1

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 20px;
  margin: 15px auto;
  font-size: 0;
}
.container > div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.container > div:nth-of-type(1) {
    width: 20%;
} 
.container > div:nth-of-type(2) {
  width: 80%;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
.btn-download {
  min-width: 110px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
}
.btn-download:before {
  content: '\f019';
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.btn-download:hover {
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.2/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <a href="documents/fz257.doc" target="_blank" class="btn-download">СКАЧАТЬ</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p style="font-size: 20px; color: #3b4146;">- ФЗ РФ № 257 "Об автомобильных дорогах и о дорожной деятельности в Российской Федерации и о внесении изменений в отдельные законодательные акты Российской Федерации"</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div>
    <a href="documents/fz257.doc" target="_blank" class="btn-download">СКАЧАТЬ</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p style="font-size: 20px; color: #3b4146;">- ФЗ РФ № 257 "Об автомобильных дорогах и "</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div>
    <a href="documents/fz257.doc" target="_blank" class="btn-download">СКАЧАТЬ</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p style="font-size: 20px; color: #3b4146;">- ФЗ РФ № 257 "Об автомобильных дорогах и о дорожной деятельности в Российской Федерации и о внесении изменений в отдельные законодательные акты Российской Федерации"</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Вариант 2

```css
.container{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 10px;
    margin: 15px auto;
}
.container > div{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle; 
    padding: 0 10px;
}
.container > div:nth-of-type(1){
    width: 20%;
}
.btn-download{    
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    background: #555;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px 15px;
}
.btn-download:before{
    content: '\f019';
    font-family: FontAwesome;    
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: 5px;    
}
.btn-download:hover{
    background: #000;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.2/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div>    
    <a href="documents/fz257.doc" target="_blank" class="btn-download">СКАЧАТЬ</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p style="font-size: 20px; color: #3b4146;">- ФЗ РФ № 257 "Об автомобильных дорогах и о дорожной деятельности в Российской Федерации и о внесении изменений в отдельные законодательные акты Российской Федерации"</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div>    
    <a href="documents/fz257.doc" target="_blank" class="btn-download">СКАЧАТЬ</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p style="font-size: 20px; color: #3b4146;">- ФЗ РФ № 257 "Об автомобильных дорогах и "</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div>    
    <a href="documents/fz257.doc" target="_blank" class="btn-download">СКАЧАТЬ</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p style="font-size: 20px; color: #3b4146;">- ФЗ РФ № 257 "Об автомобильных дорогах и о дорожной деятельности в Российской Федерации и о внесении изменений в отдельные законодательные акты Российской Федерации"</p>
  </div>
</div>
```